# activate service worker automatically (chrome extensions)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension works fine, the only problem is enabling it automatically. Whenever I start the browser the service worker won't activate unless I refresh the extensions, it says:"service worker (not active)", how do I get it to activate automatically?

The idea would be activating the service worker automatically when I start the browser instead of manually refreshing.

Comment: You need to add a listener for a [`chrome` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/) event. It's also possible you don't need the service worker at all, depending on what your extension does. Add more info to the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm My extension just checks wether or not a string is contained in the current page's URL and if that's the case it closes the current page and redirects the user to another one. The service worker file is the file containing the script for this process, what setup do you suggest?

Comment: You need a listener for chrome.tabs.onUpdated or chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.

Comment: I missplelled "addListener" a few times but now I got it to work, thanks a lot.